Rapidly-growing integer sequences with positive density
A sequence $A = (a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{Z}$ has positive upper Banach density if
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sup_h \frac{\#A \cap [h+1, h+2, \ldots, h+n]}{n} >0$$.
I know that every linear sequence (i.e. multiples of some $k \in \mathbb{N}$) has positive upper Banach density, and that polynomials and primes have upper Banach density zero.
Question. Are there examples of sequences that grow faster than linearly, but that have positive upper Banach density?
I can make some Fraenken-solutions by listing the elements of $$\{2^m + n : 1 \leq n \leq m\}$$
in increasing order, but those sequences are not really that different from linear since they have arbitrarily long chunks of consecutive integers.  I can also make more general examples by replacing the exponent $n$ by some increasing integer-valued function $f(n)$, but again, I'll get long chunks of consecutive integers.
If I similarly replace $m$ by some integer-valued function $g(m)$, how fast can $g$ grow?
Badly-phrased question. How "non-linear" can a sequence be if it has positive upper Banach density?

I guess that the set of multiples of some natural $k$ has upper Banach density not $k$, but $\frac 1k$.

You seem to distinguish, approx, between linear and polynomial, but linear is polynomial, of degree one.

First, the proposed definition of the positive upper Banach density is natural to consider for a set $A\subset \mathbb Z$ rather than for a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$. Next, for the clarity, I assume that in the definition, the domain of $h$  is $\mathbb Z$ and the domain of $n$ is $\mathbb N$.
It is easy to check that a set $A\subset\mathbb Z$ has positive upper Banach density iff there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that there are arbitrary long chunks of consecutive integers such that at least
$\varepsilon$ of all the numbers of the chunk belong to $A$. In particular, the set $A$ has positive upper Banach density provided $A$ contains arbitrary long chunks of consecutive integers. But such a subset of $\mathbb N$ can be very sparse and the increasing enumeration of the elements of $A$ can grows arbitrary fast. Namely, let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be an arbitrary function. Nevertheless the set $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} f(n)+\{1,2,\dots,n\}$$ has positive upper Banach density.

The set you are describing here is essentially the same as the example I gave (replacing $2^m$ by $2^{g(m)}$ for a suitable increasing integer-valued function $g$). Can you prove why $A \subset \mathbb{Z}$ has positive upper Banach density if and only if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that there are arbitrary long chunks of consecutive integers such that at least $\epsilon$ of the numbers in that chunk belong to $A$? The "only if" direction is clear to me, but I don't see why the "if" direction should be true.

@approximate-identity Right, all possible examples are essentially the same. The "if" direction is even more obvious than the "only if" that. Suppose that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that there are arbitrary long chunks of consecutive integers such that at least $\varepsilon>0$ of the numbers in that chunk belong to $A$. That is, for any natural $N$ there exists natural $n\ge N$ and integer $h$ such that the chunk $C={h+1, h+2, \ldots, h+n}$ contains at least $n\varepsilon$ numbers from $A$. Then $\frac{|A \cap C|}{n}\ge \varepsilon$.

Therefore the supremum limit in the definition of the positive upper Banach density is at least $\varepsilon>0$.
